# How to round a selected edge

Tags: modeling, workflow, edges

[image: round edge]

I would like to round the edge of this object without affecting any other vertices around it. That is to say, in the image shown here I only want to affect the selected strata and not the strata of vertices below it.

Comment: you can hide the vertices you don't want to affect with H

Comment: How do you unhide after the edits are done?

Comment: you unhide with Alt H

Answer (score 0):

If you mean what I think you mean, here's one way:

turn OFF proportional editing:
[image]

move the vertices you want to round way up out of the range of the proportional tool:
[image]

edit them with the proportional tool until to do whatever rounding you want:
[image]

turn OFF proportional editing again and then move them back down in place:
[image]

I know this isn't exactly what you want but it's just an example.  Hope this helps.

Comment: That's a great fix! I wish I had known that simple method because I had to do a lot of acrobatics using the smoothing tool. What a time drain that was.